# Python: Is it possible to debug with breakpoints across modules in Spyder?

Tags: python, debugging, spyder, ipdb

I use the ipython debugger interactively in Spyder. I need to debug with breakpoints across modules i.e. I'd like the debugger to step into a function that is contained within a particular .py file which isn't the .py file I start the debugger on.

At the moment, I can't seem to make this work. The debugger only 'sees' the breakpoints (which I manually add before running the debugger) in the current module. But I can't have every function in this module because it'll grow too large and it's not good practise. For testing, I really need to step into these smaller, generic functions that I hope to place in other modules.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to call your module function (the one you want to add breakpoints to) in a another file and then debug that file.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. But I want to test individual lines of the generic function... I can't do that unless I step into it...